# ajax form submit in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, validation

In my simple ajax login form. I tried to validate my form using `ajax` in codeigniter and return the message as `json` data.

The below are my codes. It gives correct output. my question is

**I used submit path in both the `form` and ajax `url`. If don't use it in both places, it won't work well. Is it a good practice? Is there any other way to do this?**

Any suggestions ?

**view_login.php**

```
<body>
    <?php
    $this->load->helper('form');
    echo form_open('login/submit', 'id="login_form"');
    echo form_input('name', '', 'id="name"');
    echo form_password('password', '', 'id="password"');
    echo form_submit('button', 'Submit', 'id="submit"');
    echo form_close();
    ?>

</body>
```

**custom.js**

```
var url = 'http://localhost/ci_test_ajax/';
function user_login(data){
return $.ajax({
    url: url+'login/submit',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data
});
}
$(function () {
var url = 'http://localhost/ci_test_ajax/';
$('#login_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('form#login_form').serialize();
    user_login(data).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
});
```

submit function in **login.php**

```
function submit()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|xss_clean|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'xss_clean|min_length[4]|required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        echo json_encode('yes');
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode('no');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was not at all a good practice,
If you are using codeigniter, try adding the base_url(); to a js variable in the header section before your custom.js file include, then access the js variable;

```
<script>
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>'; 
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any other way to avoid the `action` in form and `url` in ajax call at same time?

Answer (score 0):

if your are submitting your form through ajax , than why use 2 url you can use only one.

Try something like this

```
$(function () {
    $('#login_form').submit(function (e) {
        var url = this.action;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```